# nelder-mead, finding error on fitted parameters

Tags: python, scipy

I've been starting to use the minimizer in scipy.optimize and for most parameters I've tried to fit, the default method BFGS has worked just fine. The method helpfully reports the inverse of the Hessian matrix from which I can extract the errors on the fitted parameters from the diagonals of the matrix. However, for some new parameters that I'm trying to fit, the values are quite small and I run into precision errors using BFGS.

Switching to Nelder-Mead does the job, but I don't know how to extract the uncertainties from the fitted parameters using this method.

How can I extract the uncertainties for the fitted parameters using the Nelder-Mead in `scipy.optimize()`?

Comment: You might migrate to [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), you'll get a much better expert audience there. This is more a CV question than SO.